# Using splashtop with Ubuntu

Tags: splashtop

Recently switched to Ubuntu and I love it it made my laptop feel new and doubled my battery life. However I use splashtop to remote into people's PCs for work and sometimes i need to use windows keyboard shortcuts but they clash with Ubuntu's shortcuts, for example i click on the windows start button to bring it up for the customer but not only does that not happen but it triggers the task switcher in Ubuntu, on windows in splashtop if i had it open any keyboard commands i did only effected the PC i am remoting into but on linux it does not care any commands i use dooes not happen in he PC i remote into but happen inside linux itself like the start button or the task manager switch etc. any solution for this?